# Ionic 2: How to update Ionic library for an existing project?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

Can't find any info on Ionic 2 website. For example, a project is created with Ionic library 2.0.1. How do I update it to Ionic library 2.1.0? What is the standard procedure? `ionic lib update` is deprecated.

Comment: are you talking about CLi or project?

Comment: I'm talking about project.

Comment: Check the solution..follow the steps for updating the project..BTW which version are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to update your CLI, you need to run:

`npm install -g ionic@latest`

For updating your project, open your package.json and update the version of `ionic-angular` entry and any other dependencies that need to be updated. Reference to a package.json is [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) which is the one that is downloaded when you start a new project.

Then delete your projects `node_modules` and run:

`npm install` in your project directory.

Comment: Instead of deleting `node_modules` folder manually, can I do `npm update` or `npm uninstall` + `npm install`?

Comment: You could. But by experience I have found it causing some error or the other.

Comment: the question is the reference itself is outdated when you run `npm outdated`, so how to update to the latest version specified in `npm outdated`?

Answer (score 4):

You can also go to your project directory and type:

1. `npm install ionic-angular@latest --save`
2. `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

In my case, `npm install -g ionic@latest` installed globally the latest ionic but it didn't update the ionic version of my project. Only the above solution worked.

- PS 1: I'm using ionic 3
- PS 2: Delete the project's folder `node_modules`, in case of errors