# How to upgrade Ionic framework of my Ionic project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, ionic3

When I do `ionic info`, I see

`Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0`

I want to upgrade it to

`Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2`

I have used the command `npm install -g ionic@latest` but ionic framework has not updated. I have also remove `-g` still its not updated. What do I do ?

I need same configuration as my other project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2: How to update Ionic library for an existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591456/ionic-2-how-to-update-ionic-library-for-an-existing-project)

Comment: You could take required dependencies from package.json of that other project then just npm install

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your `package.json` file, it should be in the root directory of the app.

You will notice the versions of the app and several node modules that you are using.

Set appropriate version number, you can lookup the latest versions available here, search it here and update your package.json

`https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ionic`

Once you are done updating package.json, then delete(backup) your node_modules directory and do

`npm install`

Make sure you read release notes and change log before updating version as they have breaking changes.